# Not able to resolve error in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Sniip</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sniip</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <dependencies> //Throws an error right here
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.11.0.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am adding dependencies in pom.xml, but throws an error saying : Invalid content was found starting with the element "dependencies". Not sure if there is any restructuring required? 
I want to get my automated tests running on CI pipeline and this is one step i need to accomplish but not able to proceed .
Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: `<dependencies>` is not a child of `<build>` element. take them outside of `<build>`

Answer (score 1):

Vadim had commented the right thing asking you to remove dependencies outside your build.

In a regular maven POM this is how the structure exists

```
    <project>
        <modelVersion>X.x.x</modelVersion>
        <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
        <packaging>war/jar...</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>xxxx</name>
        <properties></properties>
        <parent></parent>
        <profiles></profiles>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency1></dependency1>
        </dependencies>
   </project>
```

Get the POM in a proper structure. If you still get a dependency related error, then it can be because

- You are inside an org network, and the org artifactory/nexus or any other repo manager does not have the dependecy.
- The dependency has some typo or version conflict.

Resolve them and see if you can proceed.